# Small objects in TOP

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Are spheres and disks small objects in TOP (more precisely, small with respect all continuos maps)?

Comment: Can you say what small means for the non-category theorists?

Comment: Or even for the category theorists, since there is more than one possible meaning...